# What's wrong with this MySQL command?

Tags: mysql

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ifm.LinksTable (
  file_system_id SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
  inode_number BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT  ,
  parent_inode_number BIG INT  ,
  virtual_name VARCHAR(256)  , 
  UNIQUE INDEX (parent_inode_number, virtual_name, file_system_id),
  inode_type CHAR(1) ,
  symbolic_link_inode BIGINT DEFAULT 0 ,
  current_version_number SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 ,
  number_of_links_to_file SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 ,
  PATH  varchar(1000),
  dir_level  INT ,
  time_last_modified INT ,
  time_last_accessed INT ,
  time_last_changed INT ,
  created_date INT ,
  permissions INT ,
  uid INT ,
  gid INT ,
  deleted_flag CHAR(1) , 
  PRIMARY KEY(file_system_id, inode_number)
);
```

The error is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'BIG INT  ,virtual_name VARCHAR(256)  , UNIQUE
>   INDEX (parent_inode_number, virtua' at line 1

Please consider that i am a novice at MySQL command, though understand SQL.

This is how the MySQL def file looks like, to which i add level aand path

```
cat ifmLinksTable.mysqldef
file_system_id,smallint not null
inode_number,bigint auto_increment
parent_inode_number,bigint
virtual_name,varchar(256) , unique index (parent_inode_number, virtual_name, file_system_id)
inode_type,char(1)
symbolic_link_inode,bigint default 0
current_version_number,smallint default 0
number_of_links_to_file,smallint default 0
time_last_modified,int
time_last_accessed,int
time_last_changed,int
created_date,int
permissions,int
uid,int
gid,int
deleted_flag,char(1), primary key(file_system_id, inode_number)
```

Comment: It's `BIGINT` not `BIG INT`

Comment: Formatting the query so it is readable would help.  But based on the error message, `BIGINT` doesn't have a space in it.

Comment: That's not the issue, BIG INT or BIGINT is untouched by me. The error happened when i tried adding dir_level and PATH to the existing query

Comment: Quick play and it seems to object to inode_number being an auto increment but not the key (although it is part of a key).

Comment: @Kickstart: Didn't understand, are you referring to my problem?

Comment: Yes. I tried you create statement (fixing the bigint issue) and it objected to inode_number giving the error `there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key` . Remocing file_system_id from the primary key definition fixed this. However this might be an issue to do with the storage engine you are using. It gives this engine using innodb but works fine with myisam.

Comment: Somewhere it seems the C++ code is unable to take the mysql def new attributes dir_level and path for some weird reason

Answer (score 0):

It should be `BIGINT`, without space, but not `BIG INT`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ifm.LinksTable (
  file_system_id SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
  inode_number BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT  ,
  parent_inode_number BIGINT  ,
  virtual_name VARCHAR(256)  , 
  UNIQUE INDEX (parent_inode_number, virtual_name, file_system_id),
  inode_type CHAR(1) ,
  symbolic_link_inode BIGINT DEFAULT 0 ,
  current_version_number SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 ,
  number_of_links_to_file SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 ,
  PATH  varchar(1000),
  dir_level  INT ,
  time_last_modified INT ,
  time_last_accessed INT ,
  time_last_changed INT ,
  created_date INT ,
  permissions INT ,
  uid INT ,
  gid INT ,
  deleted_flag CHAR(1) , 
  PRIMARY KEY(file_system_id, inode_number)
);
```

Comment: That's not the issue, it's untouched by me. The error happened when i tried adding dir_level and PATH to the existing query

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Well, this correction was based on the error stack you posted. Other issues were not reported by you. May be it would fail on primary key as you tried to define a composite that includes an auto increment field, which is not allowed.

Comment: You can define like `primary key (inode_number), unique key ( file_system_id, inode_number )`

Answer (score 0):

I see some error : parent_inode_number BIG INT => parent_inode_number BIGINT   (just some typo^^), and the other is with VARCHAR: VARCHAR max value is 255 so VARCHAR(256) and VARCHAR(1000) is impossible

Hope I help!

Comment: How do u say it is impossible for varchar 1000? Any reference, links, docs?

Comment: Interestingly it seems that they have updated the English manual pages on this (the limit is now 65535) but they haven't bothered to update the French language manual page. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Comment: yeah but after it depend on his mysql version

Comment: From your URL - "The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions." We are using 5.0.67